# How to Store Updated JSON response in sqlite database android?

Tags: android, json, sqlite, android-sqlite

So here I am getting a Json response which contains list of tables and respective data. I have manually created main.sqlite database with all tables, now I want to store the response data inside respective table.I am trying to figure out optimized way to achieve it because after every 24 hours I will be getting updated response which I will have to store again. Kindly help me with this.Thanks in advance.

Below is a sample of my JSON response

```
{
"main": {
    "tableOne": [{
        "colOne": 1,
        "colTwo": "two"
    }, {
        "colOne": 3,
        "colTwo": "three"
    }],
    "tableTwo": [{
        "colOne": 1,
        "colTwo": "two"
    }, {
        "colOne": 1,
        "colTwo": "two"
    }]
}
```

}

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far

Comment: @cricket_007 I have created all the pojos of tables , Also wrote code for databaseHelper class but I am stuck to put these data into database

Comment: Does this help?  https://guides.codepath.com/android/Local-Databases-with-SQLiteOpenHelper

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
void AddJsonToDB(String jsonString, SQLiteDatabase db) throws Exception{

    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);

    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("tableOne");

    if (jsonArray.length() == 0) return 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();

        args.put("colOne", jsonobject.getInt("colOne"));
        args.put("colTwo", jsonobject.getString("colTwo"));
        db.insert("tableOne", null, args);

    }


    jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("tableTwo");

    if (jsonArray.length() == 0) return 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();

        args.put("colOne", jsonobject.getInt("colOne"));
        args.put("colTwo", jsonobject.getString("colTwo"));
        db.insert("tableTwo", null, args);

    }

}
```